# Is it appropriate to participate in the stack overflow careers site under a pseudonym?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Will employers care?  I intentionally use pseudonyms on the internet when possible (just don't like a paper trail) but my resume and skills are legit!

Comment: This should be allowed, but users should also understand that some companies/recruiters might avoid people who use pseudonyms. (When I say "should," I mean it's my opinion, not that it's necessarily how things actually work. I'm not an SE employee.)

Comment: I didn't think to ask whether it was allowed, simply whether it was personally expedient.

Comment: This is relevant to my interests as well.

Comment: Haha love your name Bill... *whoa*, and I just realized that your website has a walrus referenced in the header.  Weird.

Comment: So your name *isn't* Walrus?

Comment: Not sure if you need to worry about paper trail, I've just tried searching for my careers profile on Google, and couldn't find it. Maybe they're not indexed?

Comment: It's more like, I just don't want myself to be out there non-anonymously whenever its not absolutely necessary.  Good to know it's safe from Google, though.

Answer (score 1):

The way I figure it - if you're going to send them your resume (which, presumably has your real name), it doesn't really matter<sup>*</sup> if you're using a pseudonym or not.

<sup>*: As long as it's tasteful.</sup>

Comment: Tasteful, like, say "Walrus the Cat"? haha

Comment: I think I might anonymize (sp?) my resume somewhat and just do it.  Thanks.

Comment: In general, I mean "tasteful" as in "super safe for work".  If it could be interpreted to be perverted, sexual, or offensive, then reconsider.  But Walrus the Cat seems fine to me.